# /’twəni/ ; /ˈtwenti/

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

> “You mean it is only ***twenty*** dollars?” ([audio linked](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/479))

I hear /**ˈtwəni**/ for *twenty*. I can see that in [/ˈtwenti/](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/curt), the /t/ sound has been weakened, in the audio. However does he weaken the /e/ sound, too,  into schwa, /ə/? If it is, do you expand the use of schwa even to this word?

Comment: I hear certainly _no_ schwa in that _twenty_. The pronunciation is very close to the _a_ in _any_, which is not a schwa. The _a_ in _dollars_ sounds more like a schwa.

Comment: In American English, it's often pronounced "twunny".  I don't hear there the "correct" crisp pronunciation whose first syllable rhymes with "hen" and whose second syllable has an articulated dental. I hear the American "twunny" with a very slight dental.

Comment: I hear a difference between the _e_ in _twenty_ and the _a_ in _dollar_. Do you hear a difference there as well, @TRomano?

Comment: The first vowel in American "twunny" comes from far back in the throat (it rhymes with money) and is voiced in the upper chest cavity, whereas the second syllable of dollar is a rhotic head vowel. The mouth is closing off and the lips are beginning to protrude slightly to produce the [r], bringing the sound forward. The two vowels are also much different in their duration.

Comment: I would describe it as "twenny", rhymes with "many".  That is how I say it.  I also pronounce dollars in the same way as the audio clip.  "Dah-lers".  East coast/mid-west/west coast accents now start to appear.

Comment: What is "it" in your comment, Wichita Steve -- how you say it, or how it's being said in the recording? Would be interesting if you hear "twenny" there.

Comment: I hear 'twenny' same as 'penny'. Used in the UK along with the pronounced T version of 'twenty'. Scottish/Australian accents might say 'twinny' same as a horses 'whinny', sometimes also saying the T as well giving 'twinty'.

Comment: @TRomano: I heard "twenny" there until I read your comment and listened again very carefully. (And if I lose focus at all, it sounds very clearly like "twenny" again.) So I think you're right that it's "twunny", but I'd never have noticed it but for your comment!

Comment: In the audio, I hear both "twenny", like "penny" and "many", and "twentee".  It is that close.
If I say 20 just a bit slower, it always becomes "twen-tee".
As in, "Yes, that is the cost.  Twentee dollars."  As a slow form I would never say "twen-nee".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question of "Does he weaken the /e/ sound, too, into a shwa, /ə/?" the answer is, *Yes, and goes further to make it a long schwa, /ɛ/.*

As to your second question, use of the schwa does indeed extend to this word, in which case the (long) schwa can either be pronounced like the common /e/ sound in p**e**nny, or like the /u/ sound in s**u**pple.

A note on the original word, twenty: there are two proper pronunciations according to both [Dictionary.com/Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/twenty) and [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/twenty); /ˈtwɛn ti/ (twen-tee) and /ˈtwʌn ti/ (twuhn-tee). Further weakening it to /ˈtwʌn i/ (twuhn-ee) as the speaker is doing in the sound byte could be considered regional dialect (and commenters in your original post have posited as much).

Comment: What is a long schwa?

Comment: A long schwa is more accurately called an "open-mid central unrounded vowel or low-mid central unrounded vowel" and you can find a brief article on it at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_central_unrounded_vowel). To illustrate, take the words _w**o**men_ and _b**i**rd_; the /ih/ sound from women is more brief than the /uhr/ sound from bird (even the phonetic representation is longer).

Comment: I thought you meant to write /ɜ/, but I roll-backed the edit. And No, the use of Schwa doesn't extend to this word, it's certainly not a long Schwa

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a schwa, but /ɛ/. It's unlikely to find schwa in stressed syllables.

The speaker pronounces *twenty* as [ˈtwɛni], more precisely:

> ### [ˈtʰw̥ɛ̈̃ni]

He has the same vowel as in *bed*, but a bit centralised and nasalised (in anticipation of the following /n/), so it sounds closer to schwa.

In most American accents, when a stressed syllable ends in an N and the next unstressed syllable starts with a T, the T is usually dropped, so *in.ter.net* becomes *innernet*, *coun.ter* becomes *counner*, *twen.ty* becomes *twenni* etc.

---

<sup>- superscript h [ʰ]: aspirated

 - two superscript dots [ ̈]: centralised

 - tilde [ ̃]: nasalised</sup>